# Simulink: Simulation in a debugging-like mode

Tags: debugging, matlab, simulink

I have another issue on Simulink:

Is it possible to pause a simulation during it's runtime? After building up several steps via "Unit Delay" I want to pause my simulation before the next step is done (for displaying values for the user to see). After - let's say - clicking the simulation shall go on one step and the procedure repeats.
In the end this should have some kind of debugging functionality.

I am not very firm how this can be realized. I guess somewhere in the simulation parameters, but where and how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three ways you could go about this that I know of.

**Method 1:**  Don't pause the simulation at all. Instead use scopes on appropriate lines to provide enough information to know what happened in the simulation.

Advantage:  You don't get bit by the order of execution and the pause of the simulation causing confusing results.

Disadvantage:  It can be tricky to "time sync" the different scoped lines in your head, especially if not all of them execute every simulation step.  (This is partially due to the fact that the scope block graphs appear as step functions, when in reality they are scatter plots.

**Method 2:**  Use the built in Simulink debugger.  (Don't get your hopes up).  Open this from the Tool>Simulink Debugger menu option in the model you are using.  This tool allows you to set breakpoints on certain blocks, step one block at a time, or some combination of the two.

Advantage:  Allows fine control of the simulation.

Disadvantage:  In practice, I find this tool to be confusing to use, and prone to crashing Matlab.  Also, be cautious of order of execution.

**Method 3:**  Create an embedded Matlab function at the beginning of your simulation order of execution.  Here is an example:

function y=func(x);
y=x;

Drop this function on one of the signal lines at the beginning of your simulation (to force the order of execution).  Then put a debug point on the y=x; line.  Now, whenever your simulation hits this line, the simulation ill be paused waiting for you to click the "continue" button in the Matlab editor.

Advantage:  Reliable, easy.

Disadvantage:  Be cautious of order of execution.

**Order of execution:**

If you are not familiar with order of execution in Simulink, I suggest you turn on "Format>Block Displays>Sorted Order" from the model menu.  This will put cryptic number/letter codes on each block that somehow indicate the order in which blocks execute in your simulation.  Depending on your model and layout, these number/letter codes might make a lot of sense, or they might not.  I don't suggest using this Sorted Order display in common practice.  Instead I recommend learning and understanding how Simulink determines the Sorted Order/Execution Order.

The important thing to remember is that the debug point (weather using the Simulink debugger or the embedded Matlab) is part of the execution order.  This means that when you hit the debug point, blocks after that point won't have updated their states.  This much makes sense, but the thing that might surprise you is that displays and scopes are often some of the last blocks to update states, even if they are hooked up to signal lines that are sourced by blocks early in the execution.  This is true even if those displays and scopes are inside of (non-atomic) subsystems, and your debug point is outside that subsystem.  You can end up in a situation where the value shown on a display or scope might be from the last time step in your simulation.

How do you work around this?  Put all of your simulation inside of an atomic subsystem, including displays and scopes.  Then put your debug point outside this subsystem.  This will guarantee that whenever the debug point is hit, the state of all of the blocks (including displays and scopes) are consistent.

If any of this doesn't make sense, let me know.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your very detailed anwer :) I think I have to try some of your suggestions. I think I will build up my simulation with "Enabled Subsystems" so I can determine, when each subsystem is handled. I think I have to test, whether Method 2 or 3 is more comfortable to use. The only thing that confuses me a little bit is, why does the Method 3 forces any order, when I drop this function on every single line? Thumbs up for your awesome answer!

Comment: You only need to create one block for method 3.  I recommend dropping it on a signal line so that you know when it runs.  For example, you could drop it on a line that is before and outside all of your subsystems.  This way you know that the debugger block will run first.  This way when the simulation pauses, all of the other blocks will be frozen at a consistent time step.